# Reapplying after South Africa visa refusal

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, south-africa

Me & my family's visitor visa for South Africa was rejected with the reason "insufficient funds" in my account. We are Indian nationals, travelled numerous countries (over 25 in past 8 years).

I didn't realized that keeping/maintaining sufficient funds in the bank statement is key importance, there fore when I can reapply our application, note that funds are already added in my account via salary transfer.

Comment: Visa examiners look at bank records to determine if the applicant can afford the trip,  if the applicant _should_ afford the trip, and to ascertain if the funds come from a legal source. This [prior Travel.SE question and answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) refers to the UK and not South Africa, but provides an extensive presentation about how bank and financial records are seen by visa examiners. It may be userful to you.